# how to put the src path of my css and resources files in a netbeans web application

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, netbeans

hi i'm working on a netbeans maven web application i'm using spring mvc and i having problems with my css and resources files they dont show in my page when i load page it shows 404 not found, i'm using java class configuration and no xmls here is my java class soring mvc configuration

my MvcConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("controller")
@EnableWebMvc  
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  


    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
    }

//  JSP VIEW-RESOLVER
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver jspViewResolver() {
       InternalResourceViewResolver bean = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
       bean.setOrder(0);
       bean.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/html/");
       bean.setSuffix(".html");
       return bean;
    }

}
```

My Root Config class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller"})
@Import({MvcConfig.class})
public class RootConfig {

}
```

my initializer class

```
public class InitrMvc implements WebApplicationInitializer{

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {        

        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(RootConfign.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherServlet = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherServlet.register(MvcConfig.class);

        // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherServlet));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(0);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }
}
```

and my controller class

@Controller
public class IncidenciaControlador {

```
@RequestMapping(value = "login/testPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String login(Model model) {



       return "login/testPage";
   }
```

}

and my project tree structure

```
MyProjectMavenWeb
  --Web Pages
      --WEB-INF
          --htmlPages
              --login
                 --testPage.html
          --resources (at the same level as htmlPages)
             --img
                logo.png
```

and my testPage.html

```
<div id="logo-group">
    <span id="logo"> <img src="../resources/img/logo.png"> </span>
</div>
```

++EDIT : i'm trying with this path  ../resources/img/logo.png

***EDIT***

Solution i tried with this tree structure suggested by a poster and it worked

```
MyProjectMavenWeb
```

--Web Pages
    --resources (at the same level as htmlPages)
      --img
        logo.png
    --WEB-INF
        --htmlPages
            --login
               --testPage.html

Comment: Your `/resources` folder should be at the same level as `WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MyProjectMavenWeb
  --Web Pages
    --resources (at the same level as htmlPages)
      --img
        logo.png
    --WEB-INF
        --htmlPages
            --login
               --testPage.html
```

Try this structure

Comment: I am really sorry. I don't understand what you are asking. Could you please check you grammar

Comment: i wanted to know, how would be the path to my .png file and resources files  if i wanted to maintain my project tree structure like the one in my question before you told to put my resources directory at the same level as my WEB-INF folder.

Comment: If you are asking, what would be the url without changing the directory tree then I think this is what you need <img src="resources/img/logo.png" />